# SUMIF not returning the expected result

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to sum the content of some cells only if the corresponding label correspond to a given string.

I used the following formula in B1`=SUMIF($E$1:$E$6,"LEFT(E1,13)=A1",$F$1:$F$6)`

but the result is not what I expect

[image]

Comment: What is in K1 cell?

Comment: sorry, it is E1. I fixed the question

Comment: Are you expecting B1 to return 20 and B2 to return 10?

Comment: yes, I want to sum up the values where the string is contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to make another column (say D) that = `=Left(E1,13)`

Then drag it down...then change your B formulas to `=SUMIF($D$1:$D$6,A1,$F$1:$F$6)`